# Binary operator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let firstPart = URL(string: "https://www.kiva.org/lend/")
        let secondPart = loans[indexPath.row].id

        let result = firstPart + secondPart
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(result as URL)
    }
```

> error: Binary operator cannot be applied to two url operands

Comment: Lookup the [URL documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url). It has methods to (hint!) *append a path component.*

Answer (score 3):

You should append the strings to each other and make that a URL.

```
let urlString = "https://www.kiva.org/lend/" + loans[indexPath.row].id
let url = URL(string: urlString)
```

Answer (score 0):

i "broke my head", but i fixed my mistake

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let firstPart = URL(string: "https://www.kiva.org/lend/\(loans[indexPath.row].id)")
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(firstPart!)
```